# C++ class with a template and different template member variables

Tags: c++, list, templates, game-development, doubly-linked-list

My apologies if the title does not accurately describe what I am trying to do.

I am working on a node/scene tree system that is based on the principle of a Doubly Linked List. My base class, `Node`, has the member functions `getParent` and `getChild` that can return the respective node above and below it. I have also implemented the subclasses `GameObject` and `Scene` that are Nodes with extra members respective to each subclass.

The idea that I'm trying to implement is that I can instantiate a `Scene` object which is a `Node<Scene>`, and then set either its child or its parent to some other `Node` class, `Scene` subclass, or a `GameObject` subclass and have access to all of their respective members and functions. This is my implementation at the moment

```cpp
template<class classType>
class Node
{
    private:
        std::string name;

        //Hypothetical thing I want to do. Parent or child can be a Node of any type
        template<class T>
        Node<T>* parent;
        template<class T>
        Node<T>* child;

    public:
        Node() {
            // Constructor things...
        };


        // Return the correct class type for the child or parent
       
        Node* getChildNode() { return child; };
        Node* getParentNode() { return parent; };

        
        // Setter functions can accept a node of any type

        template<class T>
        void setChildNode(Node<T> *new_child){
            child = new_child;
        };

        template<class T>
        void setParentNode(Node<T> *new_parent){
            parent = new_parent;
        };
}

class Scene : public Node<Scene>
{
    public:
        Scene();
        void foo();
};

class GameObject : public Node<GameObject>
{
    public:
        GameObject();
        void bar();
};
```

And the classes would hopefully be used like this:

```cpp
Scene* root = new Scene();

GameObject* platform = new GameObject();

platform->setParentNode(root); //"error: cannot convert ‘Node<Scene>*’ to ‘Node<GameObject>*’ in assignment"

platform->getParentNode().foo();  //Call function specific to a Scene class
```

Is there a way that I could achieve this functionality with what I currently have?

Comment: With a custom typelist (as `std::tuple<Scene, GameObject>`), you might be able to have next type (as known at compile time). Not sure it is what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

Templates in C++ are not a replacement for OO. Templates provide compile-time polymorphism; OO run-time. You need the latter, so you'll need a common  base class.

Comment: I'm already using `Node` as a common base class and then have subclasses for `Scene` and `GameObject`, but I don't understand how would I have a `GameObject` return a parent that could be a `Scene` or another `GameObject`? Would I just make the `parent` and `child` members of type `auto`?

Comment: @Gman0064: Node is currently not a class, Node is a class template. `Scene` is not dervied from `Node` but from `Node<Scene>`. Technically allowed, but weird.  Also, I don't know either why you're mixing Scenes and GameObjects in a single list. But since you do, the parent of either can be either. `auto` is not a magic fix. It's again compile-time polymorphism.